# Função não responde corretamente

Tags: c

Tentando calcular o volume da esfera retorna um número estranho como `-1.#QNAN0`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

float pi = 3.14;
float param(int x){
float vol,y;
y = pow(x,3);
vol = (4*y)/3*pi;
return vol;
}
int main(){
int x, y;
printf("Digite o raio de uma esfera: ");
scanf(" %f", &x);
y = param(x);
printf("\nO volume de uma esfera eh %f \n", y);
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: O resultado e o raio está definido como número inteiro `int`. Salve as variáveis como `float`, ideal para trabalhar com números quebrados:
` float x, y; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu nem consegui compilar esse código porque uso um compilador moderno e configurado para dar mais qualidade ao código. Quando altero para compilar não há erro, ficou assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#ifndef M_PI
#    define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
#endif
float param(float x) {
    return (4 * pow(x, 3)) / 3 * M_PI;
}
int main() {
    float x;
    printf("Digite o raio de uma esfera: ");
    scanf(" %f", &x);
    printf("\nO volume de uma esfera eh %f \n", param(x));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/wFP87o). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/zcqhudzi-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Typing/Radius.c).

Talvez o maior problema é declarar a variável como inteiro e tentar pegar como valor decimal, tem que escolher qual vai usar e manter sincronizado. O resto foi só simplificação e padronização do código.